# Creating new layers using ArcPy to define Definition Query for each field value?

Tags: arcpy, definition-query

I am trying to set multiple definition queries for one layer based on one field using python.  ie.  I have a City layer with a field that holds the city name.  I want a copy of the layer in an MXD with the Definition query set for each value in the City field.  So essentially, I have one source layer, with a copy of the layer as many times as there are values in the City field.  The query would look like this: CITY = 'Atlanta'

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved with use of a SearchCursor. Let's assume `mxd` is your map document object, `df` is your data frame object, and `fc` is your feature class. Also, `CITY` is the name of your field. Try something like this:

```
from arcpy import *

field = "CITY"

env.overwriteOutput = True

#Create cursor to iterate rows
cursor = da.SearchCursor (fc, field)
for row in cursor:
    #sql statement for a single feature
    sql = '"{0}" = \'{1}\''.format (field, row[0])
    #Make layer with sql for one feature only. Name layer City name
    MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, row[0], sql)   
    #Make mapping layer object
    lyr = mapping.Layer(row[0])
    #Add mapping layer object to map
    mapping.AddLayer (df, lyr)
del cursor
mxd.save ()
```

Comment: A related answer here: [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372213/create-dynamic-layer-for-each-unique-value-make-feature-layer-parameters-are-n](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/372467/135445).

Answer (score 3):

The Help page on  [Layer (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000) has sample code at the end which shows a simple loop that you can easily adapt to change the layer property *definitionQuery*.

Comment: I can set the definition query using Python and the layers in the data frame. But, I want it to copy and paste the feature class in the TOC and apply a definition query for every City in the feature class.