# Create dynamic layer for each unique value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, layers, error, definition-query

*I'm new to ArcPy.*

I'm trying to [write a script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372031/creating-dynamic-layers-on-feature-class-for-each-unique-value-in-field-using-ar) that will loop through the unique values in a field in a FC and create **dynamic** layers, with definition queries, for each unique value.

- Each of the dynamic layers would all point to the same master feature class.
- I do **not** want to output static feature classes. For example, I **can't** use the *split by attributes* tool for this.

---

I've attempted to adapt an [ArcPy script from a related answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/129957/135445) to do it:

```
from arcpy import *

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
fc = "WO_VW_FGDB"
field = "CLASSIFICATIONID"

env.overwriteOutput = True

#Create cursor to iterate rows
cursor = da.SearchCursor (fc, field)
for row in cursor:
    #sql statement for a single feature
    sql = '"{0}" = \'{1}\''.format (field, row[0])
    #Make layer with sql for one feature only. Use the field value as the layer name.
    MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, row[0], sql)   
    #Make mapping layer object
    lyr = mapping.Layer(row[0])
    #Add mapping layer object to map
    mapping.AddLayer (df, lyr)
del cursor
mxd.save ()
```

When I run the script in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1, it successfully creates the first layer. In fact, it actually creates duplicate layers.

But then it produces an error:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 17, in <module>   
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6986, in MakeFeatureLayer     
raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Make Feature Layer). Parameters are not valid. 
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter in_features.
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post you referred  deals with city names that are supposedly unique. You need to create unique list of values and iterate through it.

Comment: Unique vals can be generated using a python `set`.  i.e `uniquevals = set((row[0] for row in cursor))` which you can then loop through i.e `for val in uniquevals"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script works in ArcGIS Pro 2.4 (but not ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1.):

```
def DuplicateLayer(CopyLayer, field, uniquevalue):
    p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")
    m = p.listMaps("Map")[0]
    LayerToDup = m.listLayers(CopyLayer)[0]
    print(LayerToDup.name)
    m.addLayer(LayerToDup, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
    LayerToDup.name = str(CopyLayer)
    lyr = m.listLayers(CopyLayer)[0]
    lyr.definitionQuery = field + " = '" + uniquevalue + "'"
    lyr.name = uniquevalue
    print (lyr.definitionQuery)
    
def unique_values(layer, field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

def ExplodeFC(layername,field):
    fieldvals = unique_values(layername,field)
    for value in fieldvals:
        DuplicateLayer(layername,field,value)
 
ExplodeFC("WO_VW_FGDB","CLASSIFICATIONID")
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a list of unique field values.  Use a function like the one below:

```
def unique_values(table , field, criteria = None):
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field], criteria) as cursor:
    
    vals = set({row[0] for row in cursor})
    if (None in vals):
        vals.remove(None)
    if ('' in vals):
        vals.remove('')    
    
    return sorted(vals)
```

Then as a seperate step loop through those values creating your layers.  E.g.

```
vals = unique_values(fc)
for v in vals :
     
    sql = '"{0}" = \'{1}\''.format (field, v)
    MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, v, sql)   
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks, Anna. You might be interested in what I came up with (I posted an answer below). Cheers.